# Explain how C evaluates this expression

Tags: c

```
x=4+2%-8;
```

This gives output=6
Please anyone explain how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check this [precedence chart](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) first mod is taken and then added to 4

so `(2%-8)` gives `2` 
then   `2+4 = 6`

Comment: i thought 2%8=4 ? because n%m gives reminder obtained by this  ,correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No you are wrong as 2 is less then 8 so it is certainly not divisible (unless going into fraction which doesn't happen in Mod operation)and hence any thing less than 8 will get thrown as remainder like 7%8 = 7 but 9%8 = 1. Its a simple division operation you simply don't divide anything if number to be divided is less than number dividing it as it will be less than 1

Answer (score 13):

`x=4+2%-8;` is equivalent to `x = 4 + (2 % -8);` which gives `x = 4 + 2` which is 6.

More: [C Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Comment: +1: But one gripe; the value of `(x % y)` for negative `y` is *implementation-defined* in C90.

Answer (score 3):

Because the precedence of the operator % is the highest from the equation, the program first executes the operation 2 % 8 which is 2 and the adds this to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can not divide the number 2 by 8. so no division and the number itself(2) will be the output as for the modulus value.